# Database connection test failed in web-logic server

Tags: weblogic, oracle12c, jdeveloper, oracle12.2

I am getting below error while creating data-source to a database in weblogic server 12.

```
Error Cannot load driver: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

Comment: Why are you using a SQL Server driver if you're connecting to an Oracle database; or if you are using SQL Server why have you tagged Oracle 12c (which is for the Oracle *database*, not WebLogic)? Anyway... look at your code to check which driver you're trying to use, and your CLASSPATH (maybe in your WLS start-up script) to check that is included.

Comment: I am using MS-Sql-Server as my db, it worked with correct jar file. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weblogic comes with it's own driver for sql server, `weblogic.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver` which is available in the classpath.  An example jdbc url for connecting using that driver is `jdbc:weblogic:sqlserver://SBNSWDV63\\SSQLDV03:1433;allowPortWithNamedInstance=true`

If you want to use the microsoft driver, you have to make sure the jar file containing that driver is copied to your `<domain_home>/lib` folder, so it's visible to weblogic.

Comment: Can you post the complete statck trace and the exact version of WebLogic server you are using.
Configuration steps are a bit different from a version to another.

Comment: it worked once I added the sqljdbc42.jar jar file to DefaultDomain/osb as well .